# Flutter widget test: setting padding with MediaQuery not applied

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

Since flutter's testing environment does not contain system status bar like the emulator, I would like to add padding at the top using `MediaQuery`.

Here's my testing code:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('MediaQuery padding test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    const double statusBarHeight = 24.0;

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: MediaQuery(
          data: const MediaQueryData(
            viewInsets: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
          ),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('PopupMenu Test'),
            ),
              
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    expect(find.byType(AppBar), findsOneWidget);
    expect(tester.getTopLeft(find.byType(AppBar)).dy, windowPaddingTop);
  });
}
```

Since I added `24.0` of top padding using `MediaQueryData.viewInsets`, I expected the AppBar top left y axis is `24.0`, but the result is zero.
I have also tried testing with `viewPadding` instead of `viewInsets`, but it has produced the same result.

I want to know the reason why top padding is not applied in my test, and how to solve this problem. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: just curious, what are you actually trying to test there?

Answer (score 0):

Old answer:

[You are not supposed to use MediaQuery and Scaffold this way.
MediaQuery should not be inside the widget tree and , use it to retrieve media data.
Scaffold should cover the entire screen]

Updating(based on the answer in the comments):

They are using `MediaQuery` to simulate non-safe area, like the notch in some mobile. This is used only to teste the scaffold widget against invading the safe are (like the notch).

If you just want to test, the error is here:

```
viewInsets: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
```

It should be viewPadding intead of viewInsets:

```
viewPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: viewPadding),
```

Now if you are trying to build a screen instead of test one, you don't need (and shall not) to use MediaQuery. Just use your Scaffold as the root widget.

Comment: Well first I saw testing code using MediaQuery here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/64268/files
and tried using like this way.

Comment: There is an important information there. Updating my answer.